# Can't use django management commands because of Import Errors when haystack tries to import multiligualmodel

Tags: django, import, command, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack for searching on my site.
I'm also using [django multilingual model](https://github.com/dokterbob/django-multilingual-model) for I18n.
I import MultilingualModel in search_indexes.py

I ca run all manangement commands as long as I don't have haystack in the INSTALLED_APPS.

When haystack is in the INSTALLED_APPS and try to run syncdb or migrate (and several other management commands) I'm always getting:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError haystack: cannot import name MultilingualModel
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is likely related to the hacks done in `haystack.autodiscover()`. This behavior is documented here: http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/debugging.html#import-errors-on-start-up-mentioning-handle-registrations There is a long discussion in this ticket: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/84

The long and short if it is that moving `haystack.autodiscover()` into your `urls.py` can sometimes resolve this issue. Setting `HAYSTACK_ENABLE_REGISTRATIONS = False` when running syncdb or migrate has resolved this for me using this snippet in my `settings.py`:

```
# FIXME: This is a complete hack to get around circular imports in 
# django-haystack and other apps such as django-endless-pagination
SKIP_COMMANDS = ['syncdb', 'migrate', 'schemamigration', 'datamigration']
if any([command in sys.argv for command in SKIP_COMMANDS]):
    HAYSTACK_ENABLE_REGISTRATIONS = False
```

Answer (score 0):

`search_indexes.py` doesn't get processed unless haystack is in `INSTALLED_APPS`. The problem is with the import of `MultilingualModel` in general. Either it's not truly installed in your environment (attempt to import it from a vanilla python shell), or you have the import wrong (it's actually in another module, for example).

Once you can successfully import `MultilingualModel` from a python shell, you won't have any problems.