# Best ways to deal with Haystack Import errors

Tags: django, django-haystack

Heres what I have ended up with, please let me know if you have any other ideas.

try doing this in urls.py

```
from apps.search import search_indexes

import haystack
haystack.autodiscover()
```

Won't work without import of search_indexes.

I also use this hack in settings to get management commands working:

```
SKIP_COMMANDS = ['test']
if any([command in sys.argv for command in SKIP_COMMANDS]):
HAYSTACK_ENABLE_REGISTRATIONS = False
```

taken from this post: [Can't use django management commands because of Import Errors when haystack tries to import multiligualmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577449/cant-use-django-management-commands-because-of-import-errors-when-haystack-trie)

I'm wondering about just setting HAYSTACK_ENABLE_REGISTRATIONS to false the whole time to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Setting HAYSTACK_ENABLE_REGISTRATIONS to False doesn't work.

I have however worked out a config that works for me on Django 1.4, Apache mod_wsgi, Haystack 1.2.7.

Try this config:

myapp.search_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes, site
from apps.myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
...

site.register(MyModel, MyModelIndex)
```

settings.py

```
HAYSTACK_SITECONF = 'apps.myapp.search_indexes'

SKIP_COMMANDS = ['test']
if any([command in sys.argv for command in SKIP_COMMANDS]):
    HAYSTACK_ENABLE_REGISTRATIONS = False
...
```

If only this was in the docs from the start!